# How to validate a claim in id_token when using OpenIdConnect middleware?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, openid, asp.net-core-2.0, google-workspace

I'm using Oath2 with Google authentication in my ASP.NET Core MVC app.  I want to restrict logged in users to a certain G Suite domain which according to the docs is done using the "hd" (hosted domain) claim.  I have it working but as it's authentication and I'm not familiar would like input.  Am I doing this correctly?  Is there a way to instead return a 401 status code instead of calling Fail() which results in a 500 error?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
        {
            var hostedDomain = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("hd", "mysite.com");

            o.ClientId = "...";
            o.ClientSecret = "...";
            o.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com";
            o.ResponseType = "id_token token";
            o.Scope.Add("openid");
            o.Scope.Add("email");
            o.Scope.Add("profile");
            o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            o.SaveTokens = true;
            o.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                {
                    // Add domain limiting using 'hd' or 'hosted domain' parameter
                    // Docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param
                    //context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter(hostedDomain.Key, "asdf.com");

                    // Set up redirect URLs
                    if (context.Request.Path != "/account/external")
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/account/login");
                        context.HandleResponse();
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },

                OnTokenValidated = (c) =>
                {
                    var hdClaim = c.SecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == hostedDomain.Key);
                    if(hdClaim?.Value == null || hdClaim.Value != hostedDomain.Value)
                    {
                        // The claim is null or value is not the trusted google domain - do not authenticate!
                        c.Fail($"Invalid claim for '{hostedDomain.Key}'!  User does not belong to trusted G Suite Domain");
                    }
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }


            };
        });

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

The above works when an incorrect or null hd claim is given which is done by logging in with an account not in the domain name in the `hostedDomain.Value`.  I tried setting the `c.Response.StatusCode = 401;` but the user still logs in.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do this would be to use *authorization*.

You can set up a default authorization policy that requires the presence of the claim you test for. Then any caller that does not have the claim would get redirected to an access denied page. Something like:

```
services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
    o.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireClaim("hd", "mysite.com");
    });
});
services.AddMvc(o =>
{
    o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter("default"));
});
```